# Overriding Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type

Tags: magento-1.9, product, module, overrides

I am trying to override a model file.

The file location is: `core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type.php`

I am trying to show only simple products when creating a new product but it is not working.

directory structure and files are given as below

#### local->Divum->Catalog->etc->config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Divum_Catalog>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Divum_Catalog>
        <global>
            <models>
            <catalog>
                    <rewrite>
                    <product_type>Divum_Catalog_Model_Product_Type</product_type>
                </rewrite>
                </catalog>
            </models>
        </global>
    </modules>
</config>
```

#### local->Divum->Catalog->Model->Product->Type.php

```
class Divum_Catalog_Model_Product_Type
{
const TYPE_SIMPLE       = 'simple';
const TYPE_BUNDLE       = 'bundle';
const TYPE_CONFIGURABLE = 'configurable';
const TYPE_GROUPED      = 'grouped';
const TYPE_VIRTUAL      = 'virtual';

const DEFAULT_TYPE      = 'simple';
const DEFAULT_TYPE_MODEL    = 'catalog/product_type_simple';
const DEFAULT_PRICE_MODEL   = 'catalog/product_type_price';
static protected $_types;
static protected $_compositeTypes;
static protected $_priceModels;
static protected $_typesPriority;
public static function factory($product, $singleton = false)
{
    $types = self::getTypes();
    $typeId = $product->getTypeId();

    if (!empty($types[$typeId]['model'])) {
        $typeModelName = $types[$typeId]['model'];
    } else {
        $typeModelName = self::DEFAULT_TYPE_MODEL;
        $typeId = self::DEFAULT_TYPE;
    }

    if ($singleton === true) {
        $typeModel = Mage::getSingleton($typeModelName);
    }
    else {
        $typeModel = Mage::getModel($typeModelName);
        $typeModel->setProduct($product);
    }
    $typeModel->setConfig($types[$typeId]);
    return $typeModel;
}
public static function priceFactory($productType)
{
    if (isset(self::$_priceModels[$productType])) {
        return self::$_priceModels[$productType];
    }

    $types = self::getTypes();

    if (!empty($types[$productType]['price_model'])) {
        $priceModelName = $types[$productType]['price_model'];
    } else {
        $priceModelName = self::DEFAULT_PRICE_MODEL;
    }

    self::$_priceModels[$productType] = Mage::getModel($priceModelName);
    return self::$_priceModels[$productType];
}
static public function getOptionArray()
{
    $options = array();
    foreach(self::getTypes() as $typeId=>$type) {
         if($typeId == 'simple'):
            $options[$typeId] = Mage::helper('catalog')->__($type['label']);
        endif;
    }

    return $options;
}
static public function getAllOption()
{
    $options = self::getOptionArray();
    array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>''));
    return $options;
}
static public function getAllOptions()
{
    $res = array();
    $res[] = array('value'=>'', 'label'=>'');
    foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
        $res[] = array(
           'value' => $index,
           'label' => $value
        );
    }
    return $res;
}
static public function getOptions()
{
    $res = array();
    foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
        $res[] = array(
           'value' => $index,
           'label' => $value
        );
    }
    return $res;
}
static public function getOptionText($optionId)
{
    $options = self::getOptionArray();
    return isset($options[$optionId]) ? $options[$optionId] : null;
}
static public function getTypes()
{
    if (is_null(self::$_types)) {
        $productTypes = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/catalog/product/type')->asArray();
        foreach ($productTypes as $productKey => $productConfig) {
            $moduleName = 'catalog';
            if (isset($productConfig['@']['module'])) {
                $moduleName = $productConfig['@']['module'];
            }
            $translatedLabel = Mage::helper($moduleName)->__($productConfig['label']);
            $productTypes[$productKey]['label'] = $translatedLabel;
        }
        self::$_types = $productTypes;
    }

    return self::$_types;
}
static public function getCompositeTypes()
{
    if (is_null(self::$_compositeTypes)) {
        self::$_compositeTypes = array();
        $types = self::getTypes();
        foreach ($types as $typeId=>$typeInfo) {
            if (array_key_exists('composite', $typeInfo) && $typeInfo['composite']) {
                self::$_compositeTypes[] = $typeId;
            }
        }
    }
    return self::$_compositeTypes;
}
public static function getTypesByPriority()
{
    if (is_null(self::$_typesPriority)) {
        self::$_typesPriority = array();
        $a = array();
        $b = array();

        $types = self::getTypes();
        foreach ($types as $typeId => $typeInfo) {
            $priority = isset($typeInfo['index_priority']) ? abs(intval($typeInfo['index_priority'])) : 0;
            if (!empty($typeInfo['composite'])) {
                $b[$typeId] = $priority;
            } else {
                $a[$typeId] = $priority;
            }
        }

        asort($a, SORT_NUMERIC);
        asort($b, SORT_NUMERIC);

        foreach (array_keys($a) as $typeId) {
            self::$_typesPriority[$typeId] = $types[$typeId];
        }
        foreach (array_keys($b) as $typeId) {
            self::$_typesPriority[$typeId] = $types[$typeId];
        }
    }
    return self::$_typesPriority;
}
}
```

#### app->etc->modules->You_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Divum_Pricing>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Divum_Pricing>
        <Divum_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Divum_Adminhtml>
        <Divum_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Divum_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

When I put the same code in the core file which is located in 
`core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type.php`, it is working but it is not working in the overridden file.

I think I made a mistake in the config file but I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Did you set up the `<depends><Mage_Catalog /></depends>` in your module definition file?

Comment: No.. i don't know where to put... can you please help me.. in which file do i have to put this line ?

Comment: `app/etc/modules/You_Module.xml`. If you don't have this file, your module is not registered to Magento, so it's completely ignored.

Comment: Yes i have this file ... and my module is appear in back end..

Comment: have you extends class Divum_Catalog_Model_Product_Type to Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your config.xml is badly formatted. You have the `<global>` node inside the `<modules>` node but it should be a sibling not a child of `<modules>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Divum_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Divum_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_type>Divum_Catalog_Model_Product_Type</product_type>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Secondly if you are going to do a rewrite of a class you should first extend the class you are rewriting.

```
class Divum_Catalog_Model_Product_Type extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type
```

Then in this class you simply need to have your changes and not the complete file as you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/ it help you to understand how to override

Comment: Though this could answer help the person out links can die. Could you maybe include the important information for the question asked?

Answer (score 0):

i have find the problem.

the problem is nothing but the 
"global" tag is inside the  tag. all i need to do is just place the "global" tag outside the  tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Divum_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Divum_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_type>Divum_Catalog_Model_Product_Type</product_type>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the very rare cases in Magento where a class is not used with the factory methods like `Mage::getModel()`.

Actually `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type` only contains **static** methods, which makes it play in the same league as the `Mage` class itself and totally different from all other model classes.

**Ergo, you cannot rewrite it.**

What makes it really evil is that it might *seem* to work because in some places Magento instantiates the class with `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')` but in other cases it calls the methods statically.

#### For example:

- In `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Prodcut_Flat_Indexer` the static call is used:

  ```
  foreach (array_keys(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::getTypes()) as $typeId) {
  ```
- In `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` the singleton is used:

  ```
  $this->addColumn('type',
      array(
          'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Type'),
          'width' => '60px',
          'index' => 'type_id',
          'type'  => 'options',
          'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray(),
  ));
  ```

*(in case you are wondering, calling static methods on an instance is totally allowed in PHP)*