# How to set "Configurable" as a default product type on Magento's new product 1st step?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, configurable-product

When we click to create a new product, the default option is "Simple product". Is there a way to set "Configurable" as default option since the store will always work with configurable products?

[image]

Comment: The sort order is coming from `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\etc\config.xml` file. Inside that find `global/catalog/product/type` Node. You will see its defined there. Now my guess is you cant override the sorting order or manipulate it. You can add something to it but not sure if you can change the order there. Rest what you can do is add a javascript code `which may look like this document.getElementById('product_type').value='configurable';` to that particular page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom javascript code in that admin page. The code should set selected option for that dropdown.

You can achieve this by including custom javascript file in this controller using its handler **xml** file.

Answer (score 0):

Someone already tried to override the product type, please check the link and look for the comments

[Override Mage Catalog Model Product Type](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84145/overriding-mage-catalog-model-product-type)